# Get the literal value of a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable my_var declared in javascript. 
How do I get the literal string value of this variable.

The reason behind this is I need to design a generic function like this:

```
function (myvar){
$('#'+ "myvar").show();
var = ....;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarify, the function should be function (myvar){
$('#'+ "myvar").show();
myvar = ....;
}

Comment: I want to use both variable myvar and string value "myvar" in the same function

Comment: What do you want to do with the string value?

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a reserved word in javsacript you will need to change the parameter name in the function.

```
function (myVariable){
    $('#'+ myVariable).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a reserved word (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

You need to use something else, like `some_var`.
Thus, giving you:

```
function (some_var){
   $('#'+ some_var).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an effective way of using reflection in JavaScript. When I had this same requirement I ended up using an object as a parameter instead

```
function test(args) {
    for(var item in args) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(args[item]);
    }
}

test({
    myvar1:"value of myvar1",
    myvar2:"value of myvar2",
    somenumber:50
});
```

this will print

> myvar1
>
> value of myvar1
>
> myvar2
>
> value of myvar2
>
> somenumber
>
> 50

**Edit**

More relevant example:

```
function doStuff (oMyVar){
    for(var item in oMyVar) {
        alert(item);                // alerts "myvar"
        alert(oMyVar[item]);        // alerts 22

        $('#'+ item).show();        // show the element
        oMyVar[item] = 33;          // changes 22 to 33
    }
}

var v = {'myvar':22};

// before call
alert(v.myvar);                     // prints 22

// to call
doStuff(v);

// after call
alert(v.myvar);                     // prints 33
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that your solution deem myvar1 and myvar2 as string in json object.

Comment: Yes. The string is the name of the `myvar1` property. To get the value of the property use `args[myvar1]` This would get the typed value of the property

Comment: @aladine, I've updated my answer to include a more detailed example